# PHP : Bind Cookie set on Subdomain to Main Domain and all Subdomains

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

*I'm using this login script, http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/cool-login-system-php-jquery/*

I'm setting a cookie on encrypted.site.com, but I also want it to function on site.com and *.site.com. How could I do this?

It sets 2 cookies, tzLogin & tzRemember, one permanent, one session cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Set the 5th parameter (domain) to allow for any subdomains by prefixing a period. This will allow requests for `site1.site.com`, `site2.site.com` as well as `site.com` to send the cookie along:

```
setcookie('cookiename', 'cookiedata', time()+86400, '/', '.site.com');
```

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Where's the setcookie thing though, as I see `session_set_cookie_params(10000*7*24*60*60);` but no straight setcookie?

Comment: I see `setcookie('tzRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);` on line 65 of `demo.php`. You can put `10000*7*24*60*60` in place of `time()+86400` and delete the call to `session_set_cookie_params` altogether.

Comment: That sets it for the cookie tzRemember, but not tzLogin. How could I change this?

Comment: You never mentioned it was a session cookie in your original question (the script you link to sets more than one cookie). Please edit your question to include that this is for a session cookie.